# How to remove table by manipulating template in PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I am working on some report generation module with PHPWord. I load a template document file from server. I need to add dynamic row to a table if data is available in database. If there is no data in the database i wants to remove table from loaded template file. Is there any way to remove table from a loaded template file using phpword?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve this by wrapping a template block around your table and using cloneBlock function:

```
if ('there-is-data-to-be-added')
{
    // show the template table normally
    $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('TABLE-WRAP', 1);

    // clone your row(s) with your data
    $templateProcessor->cloneRow('ROW-TEMPLATE', 10);

    // add your data to the cloned rows...
}
else
{
    // hide the table (note that deleteBlock function doesn't seem to work when you have other template fields inside the table)
    $templateProcess->cloneBlock('TABLE-WRAP', 0);
}
```